# Get Browser Error. This page can’t be displayed. •Make sure the web address http://0.0.0.0:3000 is correct

Tags: php, installation, aptana

The php code is error free but when I execute RUN in Aptana the Explorer browser started by Aptana displays the error: "This page can't be displayed. Make sure the web address http:/ /0.0.0.0:3000 is correct". I'm new to Aptana and I've spent two days working though setup issues including half a day on this one. I can't find anything on Aptana's site, the web in general or stackoverflow that discusses this error other than a Rails discussion about the difference between using http:/ /0.0.0.0:3000 and http:/ /localhost:3000. The address http:/ /0.0.0.0:3000 seems to be hard-coded into the Aptana Preferences. The Aptana documentation assumes the setup will occur without any problems but once you encounter a setup or execution issue you're pretty much on you own. I now understand why newbies get frustrated with Aptana and just quit. Can anyone offer any insight into how I can resolve this problem?

Aptana Studio 3
Windows 7
php project

Answer (score 0):

"0.0.0.0" is an indication to the TCP/IP OS module that it should bind the socket to all IPv4 addresses assigned to all interfaces on the machine. You should not attempt to use it in a URL, but instead pick one of the existing, real IPv4 addresses (e.g. 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you encounter this error while running Apache with Aptana check your Apache httpd.conf file to ensure the DocumentRoot in the configuration file and the DocumentRoot in your installation documentation are the same. Solution: Move project files to Apache httpd.conf DocumentRoot location.